Applying the Mixed-Product Property of the Kronecker Product to DFT and Identity Matrices of difference sizes
Suppose we have four matrices, $\mathbf{F}_{N_2}, \mathbf{F}_{N_1}, \mathbf{I}_{M_1}, \mathbf{I}_{M_2}$, where $\mathbf{F}_{N_1}$ and $\mathbf{F}_{N_2}$ are a DFT matrix of size $N_1$ and $N_2$, respectively. Besides, $\mathbf{I}_{M_1}$ and $\mathbf{I}_{M_2}$ are the identity matrix of size $M_1$ and $M_2$, respectively. Also, we have the mixed-product property for the Kronecker product as
\begin{equation}
{\displaystyle (\mathbf {A} \otimes \mathbf {B} )(\mathbf {C} \otimes \mathbf {D} )=(\mathbf {AC} )\otimes (\mathbf {BD} ).}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf {A}, \mathbf {B}, \mathbf {C}$ and $\mathbf {D}$ are matrices of such size that one can form the matrix products $\mathbf {AC}$ and $\mathbf {BD}$.
Now, the problem in my case is how can we using mixed-product property for the following term (or any other property that makes this formula simpler)
\begin{equation}
{\displaystyle (\mathbf {F}_{N_2} \otimes \mathbf {I}_{M_2} )(\mathbf {F}_{N_1}^H \otimes \mathbf {I}_{M_1} )}
\end{equation}
where $(.)^H$ is the Hermitian operator.
NOTE: $M_1\times N_1 = M_2\times N_2$

$\def\C{\mathbb{C}}$If $A \in \C^{n\times m}$, $B \in \C^{p\times r}$, $C \in \C^{m\times s}$, $D \in \C^{r\times q}$ then $A \otimes B \in \C^{(n\times p) \times (m \times r)}$ and $C \otimes D \in \C^{(m\times r) \times (s \times q)}$ so  $(A\otimes B)(C\otimes D) \in \C^{(n \times p)\times(s \times q)}$; also since $AC \in \C^{n \times s}$ and $BD \in \C^{p \times q}$, $(AC) \otimes (BD) \in \C^{(n \times p)\times(s \times q)}$. The matrices in the Kronecker product you wrote do not satisfy any of these properties.

@TedBlack I understand your point. But, is there any other property that can be applied to my case? Since the overall dimension of the two parenthesis match each other.

$\def\vb#1{\mathbf{#1}}$ You could use the property that $\vb{F}_{n\times m}=\vb{F}_n \otimes \vb{F}m$ and $\vb{I}{n\times m}=\vb{I}_n \otimes \vb{I}_m$.

@OmidAbasi In general, there's not much that can be done here, but perhaps there's some relationship between the sizes we can take advantage of here. Do $N_1,N_2$ have any common factors (or are they relatively prime)? Same question for $M_1$ and $M_2$.

If $N_2$ is a multiple of $N_1$, I would recommend rewriting
$$
F_{N_2} \otimes I_{M_2} = F_{N_1} \otimes F_{d} \otimes I_{M_2},\
F_{N_1} \otimes I_{M_1} = F_{N_1} \otimes I_d \otimes I_{M_2},
$$
where $d = N_2/N_1 = M_1/M_2$.

Dear @BenGrossmann, generally, the selection of $M_1,M_2$ and $N_1,N_2$ is discretionary. However, we should take into account two important criteria: firstly, $N_1\neq N_2$, $M_1\neq M_2$, and secondly,  $M_1\times N_1$ should be equal to the product of $M_2\times N_2$."

@OmidAbasi I doubt that there is a useful way to rewrite this that accounts for all possible choices of $M_i,N_i$ for which $M_1 N_1 = M_2N_2$. For one thing, I see no good way to handle the case where $M_1 = N_2$ and $M_2 = N_1$, especially when $M_1, N_1$ are relatively prime. However, there are special cases that can be addressed, as I indicate in my previous two comments.
